# Static fields/methods in e

Tags: specman, e

Is there any technical reason I am missing for which *e* doesn't have static fields/methods?

I've looked up the LRM and there is no mention of anything like this. There are workaround (like this one: http://www.specman-verification.com/index.php?entry=entry060612-105347), but I don't find it a particularly clean approach as it's not nicely encapsulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. There should be no such technical reasons to not have it, and it might be a good idea to add static members to *e* structs. Its semantics would just need to be carefully considered, because of the aspect-oriented features of *e*, which are irrelevant to some other languages that have static members (for example, one question that would need to be answered is whether static methods can be extended, e.g., with `is also` or not).

However, it doesn't seem very critical to me, because a static field is, effectively, no more than a global field (or method, or any other kind of struct member) that belongs to a given struct's namespace. So, even without having static members, an easy workaround is to add such a member to `global` (or to `sys`), and make sure that its name has a prefix that makes it clear to "belong" to a given struct.

There is an important point, though, which does make static members more than just a member of `global`. In *e*, like in C++, there are `template` types. A static member of a `template` would be something that, on the one hand, is shared by all instance *objects* of a given *template instance* type, but on the other hand, would exist separately for each template instance (each one of which being a separate struct).

Not sure if the port-based workaround suggested at the above link is any better. I see it as an overkill.

Comment: While I do agree that using `global` is a better way of doing (and cleaner), it still has the problem of not being well encapsulated. There is the (albeit very small) possibility that the field we want to define might clash with another field from some other code we import.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in my previous answer I am missing an important point, which does make static members more than just a member of `global`.

In *e*, like in C++, there are `template` types. A static member of a `template` would be something that, on the one hand, is shared by all instance *objects* of a given *template instance* type, but on the other hand, would exist separately for each template instance (each one of which being a separate struct).

Comment: Hi Yuri! You're just the man I hoped would answer this question. I'll copy the text from this answer to the previous one and accept that one as a complete answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

By the way static struct members were added to the language in Specman v15.2. They are handy especially in configuration structs that are well, static:

```
extend packet_s {
  static max_address : uint = 0x1000;
};

-- Change max_address for all instances
on xxx { packet_s::max_address = 0x2000; };
```

A static field can't be generated, physical(%) or used in when subtypes. Here's some comments from the teamspecman blog : [Static members in e](http://cadence-fv.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=3180846&item=247)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason why e doesn't have static struct members yet is the fact that you always have global and sys singletons as well as top unit of your specific module (which means better encapsulation), where the 'static' information can be placed. There is no special technical reason for that, besides some complexity in defining exact semantics.

As a syntactic sugar for the unit access, you can always wrap it with very basic single-word macro - it will not be completely seamless, because this magic word will always be required vs. natively visible static struct members of 'me', but still very easy to use.

Comment: Hi Rodion, what do you mean by a top unit of a specific module?

Comment: I meant that if you are working on some specific component, related to a particular purpose (like monitor) or particular part of the DUT (like usb controller), you probably have some top unit, which is used for the instantiation of this component, and it always presents when this code should run. Of course, if your code is very generic, you can rely only on global or sys.

Comment: I was using the word "module" in general sense, not as an 'e' term.